# SSRS Tablix displayed side by side or on another page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS (SSDT 2012) report that I want to have a tablix display beside another on or be on another page.

Essentially I want to give the user the ability to select a drop down that says "Side by Side" or "On Separate Page". Depending on which one they select it will flip on the page break or turn it off. I have all of this part working.

The issue is because the tablix are side by side on the form the page break will not cause the second tablix to break at the end of the first tablix. I still see both tablix on the first page.

The work around is to replicate the second tablix below the first and just hide or unhide depending on the option selected. This is not ideal because I have to maintain separate tablix with the same data.

Is this possible? Or is my workaround the best solution?

Comment: How did you put the page break? using a rectangle?

Comment: I put it in the tablix itself. Then enabled or diabled it.

Comment: Add a rectangle between the tablix, in rectangle properties select add page break after.

Comment: Still not working. I tried to even drop the second tablix down a pixel. Even so, I don't think what I am trying to accomplish will work because the tablix to the right will not be aligned left on the second page. Unless there is some way to force it over all the way left.